# Interger List Reversal producing a NoneType Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to reverse a list of integers, but I keep getting a `NoneType` error.

```
some_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77]

reversed_numbers = []

i = 0

while some_numbers:
    reversed_numbers = reversed_numbers.insert(i, some_numbers.pop())
    i = i + 1


print(reversed_numbers)
```

Traceback (most recent call last): line 7, in

```
reversed_numbers = reversed_numbers.insert(i, some_numbers.pop())
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'

I realize I could just use `.append` and simplify the process, but the challenge specifically calls for `.insert` and a `while` loop, I think I might be way off, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `reversed_numbers = reversed_numbers.insert(i, some_numbers.pop())` when you just need to call `insert()` on `reversed_numbers` (without reassigning values).

```py
some_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77]
reversed_numbers = []
i = 0
while some_numbers:
    reversed_numbers.insert(i, some_numbers.pop())
    i += 1


print(reversed_numbers)
```

Also note that your post has `i = 0` inside your while loop, so you'd be overwriting the same index every time.

Answer (score 1):

your issue is happening on the second iteration of your while loop, in the first iteration `reversed_numbers.insert(i, some_numbers.pop())` will return `None` so `reversed_numbers`  will become `None`

---

to reverse your list you could use the built-in function `reversed` :

```
list(reversed(some_numbers))
```

---

or you can use:

```
some_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77]

reversed_numbers = []

while some_numbers:
    reversed_numbers.append(some_numbers.pop())


print(reversed_numbers)
```

---

if you want to use the `while` loop with `list.insert` you could use:

```
some_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,44,55,66,77]

reversed_numbers = []

i = 0
while some_numbers:
    reversed_numbers.insert(i, some_numbers.pop())
    i += 1


print(reversed_numbers)
# [77, 66, 55, 44, 33, 22, 11, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```